# Solving definite integrals with an even function

Tags: calculus

Find $\int_{-2}^2(2·ƒ (x)+3·g(x))dx$  is an even function such that 
 $\int_{0}^2 ƒ(x)dx=3$ and $g(x)$ is  $\int_{-2}^4g(x)dx=-3$, and $\int_{2}^4g(x)dx=-6$

I know that $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)+g(x) dx=\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx+\int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx$$
$$c\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx=\int_{a}^{b} cf(x) dx$$
$$\int_{a}^{c} f(x) dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx+\int_{b}^{c}f(x) dx$$

So would the answer look something like this:
 $2(3)-3(-3-(-6)=-3$

Also, does it matter that the question says the function is even?

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by the first line? "Find [...] is an even function" doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: find the integral

Comment: I think that $f$ is the  even fuction. yes ???

Comment: So am I doing the right thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is even, then $$\int_{-2}^22f(x)\,dx=2\int_{0}^22f(x)\,dx=4\int_{0}^2f(x)\,dx=12$$

the rest is good

Comment: Can I ask where $4$ and $12$ come from? Sorry I just want to understand every detail

Comment: Yes if $f$ is even then also $2f$ is even, Now for all even function $F$,  $\int_{-a}^{a}F=2\int_0^{a}F$, and then $2\int_{0}^22f(x)\,dx=2\cdot2\int_{0}^2f(x)\,dx=4\int_{0}^2f(x)$, because $2$ is a constant, is know   also that $\int_{0}^2f(x)\,dx=3$, then $4\int_{0}^2f(x)=4\cdot3=12$

Comment: so then is this how I solve for the integral? $12−3(−3−(−6)=3$

Comment: Yes is correct $12−3(−3−(−6))=3$.

Comment: I think something is wrong because when I submitted the answer it was wrong

Comment: Ummm ok there is a mistake is $12+3(−3−(−6))=21$, is + no -.